# Questions on pandas moving average

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner of python and pandas. I am having difficulty with making volatility adjusted moving average, so I need your help.

Volatility adjusted moving average is a kind of moving average, of which moving average period is not static, but dynamically adjusted according to volatility.

What I'd like to code is,

1. Get stock data from yahoo finance (monthly close)
2. Calculate monthly volatility X some constant --> use variables of dynamic moving average period
3. Calculate dynamic moving average

I've tried this code, but only to fail. I don't know what the problem is. If you know the problem, or any better code suggestion, please let me know.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web

def price(stock, start):
    price = web.DataReader(name=stock, data_source='yahoo', start=start)['Adj Close']
    price = price / price[0]
    a = price.resample('M').last().to_frame()
    a.columns = ['price']
    return a


a = price('SPY','2000-01-01')
a['volperiod'] = round(a.rolling(12).std()*100)*2
for i in range(len(a.index)):
    k = a['price'].rolling(int(a['volperiod'][i])).mean()
    a['ma'][i] = k[i]

print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all: you need to calculate `pct_change` on `price` to calculate `volatility` of `returns`

***my solution***

```
def price(stock, start):
    price = web.DataReader(name=stock, data_source='yahoo', start=start)['Adj Close']
    return price.div(price.iat[0]).resample('M').last().to_frame('price')

a = price('SPY','2000-01-01')

v = a.pct_change().rolling(12).std().dropna().mul(200).astype(int)

def dyna_mean(x):
    end = a.index.get_loc(x.name)
    start = end - x.price
    return a.price.iloc[start:end].mean()

pd.concat([a.price, v.price, v.apply(dyna_mean, axis=1)],
          axis=1, keys=['price', 'vol', 'mean'])
```

Comment: @WookeunLee if this answered your question, consider clicking the check signifying this as the chosen answer.

Comment: I've just checked. Is this right? I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: I think "a.price.iloc[start:end].mean()" ---> should be "return a.price.iloc[start+1:end+1].mean() 
 What does 'x.name' mean? I can't find any explanation from any document.

Comment: @WookeunLee as I use the `apply`, `x.name` will contain the `date` that was in the index for that row.  I then look for that `date`'s position in `a`'s index and mark it as `end`.  The +1 thing would be more correct in this case.  I'll follow up later with additional comments.

Comment: can you explain me what the x.price and v.price mean?@piRSquared

Comment: `x.price` is the price column for x.  `v.price` is the price column for `v`